# Expression Func and action how to pass a value form func to action

Tags: c#, expression

I have a class that has 2 methods:

`MaxLength(string text, int maxLength, string propName, string message = null);`
`MinValue(int value, int min, string propName, string message = null);`

As user could consume it by passing in each of the values.  I want to make it easier and more like automapper when they want to validate a class.  such as

```
public class MyModel {
   public string Category { get; set; }
   public int Number { get; set; }
}
```

at the moment they would have to write

```
MyModel model = //comes from API call or where ever
var validator = new Validator();
validator.MaxLength(model.Category, 4, "Category");
validator.MinValue(model.Number , 3, "Number ");
```

what I want to achieve is being able to setup mappings for the class:

```
public class Profile1 : ClassValidationProfile
{
    public Profile1()
    {
        CreateMap<Model1>()
            .ForMember(x => x.Category, m => m.MaxLength(4))
            .ForMember(x => x.Number , m => m.MinValue(3));
    }
}
```

so based on automapper I have:

```
IMappingExpression<T> ForMember<TMember>(Expression<Func<T, TMember>> member, Action<IValidatorExpression> memberAction)
```

but this would allow me to setup `.ForMember(x => x.Name, m => m.MinValue(18))` which would be incorrect and error at runtime.

I would like to be able to limit the Action `memberAction` to their correct type, (strings against string, ints for ints, etc).  So when a user is setting up their mappings it knows which action methods are valid for the property type they have given in the first part of the expression.

It could then use this information to be able to generate valid validator methods for each of the properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `Action<IValidatorExpression>`, you should use something with `TMember` to preserve the type - e.g. `Func<TMember, bool>` (a function that takes the member value as input and returns a boolean indicating whether or not validation passed).

I have tried building a little sample program, where the final validation looks like this:

```cs
var validator = Validator<MyModel>.Create()
    .ForMember(x => x.Category, cat => cat == "A")
    .ForMember(x => x.Number, num => num < 200);

MyModel model = new MyModel {
    Category = "A",
    Number = 100,
};

validator.Validate(model);
```

Is this what you were looking for?

Here's the code to achieve the above:

```cs
class Validator<TClass> {
    private List<IObjectValidator<TClass>> _constraints = new List<IObjectValidator<TClass>>();

    public static Validator<TClass> Create() {
        return new Validator<TClass>();
    }

    public Validator<TClass> ForMember<TMember>(Expression<Func<TClass, TMember>> memberSelectorExpression, Func<TMember, bool> memberValidation, string errorMessage = null) {
        _constraints.Add(new ObjectValidator<TClass, TMember>(memberSelectorExpression.Compile(), memberValidation, errorMessage ?? memberSelectorExpression.ToString() + " did not pass validation"));
        return this;
    }

    public void Validate(TClass obj) {
        foreach (var constraint in _constraints) {
            if (!constraint.Validate(obj))
                throw new Exception(constraint.ErrorMessage);
        }
    }
}

interface IObjectValidator<T> {
    bool Validate(T obj);
    string ErrorMessage { get; }
}

class ObjectValidator<T, TMember> : IObjectValidator<T>
{
    private Func<T, TMember> _memberSelector;
    private Func<TMember, bool> _memberValidation;
    public string ErrorMessage { get; }


    public ObjectValidator(Func<T, TMember> memberSelector, Func<TMember, bool> memberValidation, string errorMessage) {
        _memberSelector = memberSelector;
        _memberValidation = memberValidation;
        ErrorMessage = errorMessage;
    }

    public bool Validate(T obj)
    {
        return _memberValidation.Invoke(_memberSelector.Invoke(obj));
    }
}
```